# Is this grammar LL(1)?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, compilers

Consider following grammar:

$$X\to Yc|ZY$$

$$Y\to ab|cX$$

$$Z\to d|\epsilon$$

Can this be converted to LL(1)?

Cleary, its not LL(1) because of First/First conflict at first production. Can anyone suggest something to make it LL1?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way:

First remove the Z production:

```
X-> Yc | dY | Y
```

and leave the others intact. Now you still have the First/First conflict, but you don't need to descent to the epsilon.

Next step, introduce a new symbol Y' for deciding wether to read a c or not.

```
 X-> YY' | dY
 Y' -> c | epsilon
 Y -> ab|cX
```

now you have a first/follow conflict. How to solve that:

Let's take a look at the produced language(Assuming X is the Start symbol) and transform the grammar:

L(G) = abc or c^n ab d ab..

X-> cX| ab |abY |dX

this should be LL(1).

Comment: I did this exactly the same way but this has a first/follow conflict. both first and follow of B' have c.

Comment: ok, maybe I should go for the produced language.

Comment: Is this better now?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Aren't the 2nd and 3rd alternates same in last productiin rule?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I think I overread that I already wrote down that production.